# How can I extract data from json

Tags: python, json

I want to extract code from JSON format.

```
import json
json_data = '''
    {
        "Body": {
            "stkCallback": {
                "MerchantRequestID": "22531-976234-1",
                "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852",
                "ResultCode": 0,
                "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
                "CallbackMetadata": {
                    "Item": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Amount",
                            "Value": 1.0
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
                            "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Balance"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "TransactionDate",
                            "Value": 20190223144807
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "PhoneNumber",
                            "Value": 254725696042
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
'''

json_da = data['Body']
list_data = data['Body']['MpesaReceiptNumber']
print (json_da)
print (list_data)
```

I want to print this: `NBN52K8A1J`

Comment: That's very basic access of dicts and lists. ``data['Body']['MpesaReceiptNumber']`` will give you an *obvious* ``KeyError`` exception. Simply work your way down the main dictionary one dict/list at a time until you can access the value you want. Maybe a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) can help.

Comment: Nothing about this is specific to JSON -- the data could just be Python literals and not JSON and all, and you'd have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a list of `dict`s you need to search first:

```
>>> for obj in data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item']:
...   print(obj)
...
{'Name': 'Amount', 'Value': 1.0}
{'Name': 'MpesaReceiptNumber', 'Value': 'NBN52K8A1J'}
{'Name': 'Balance'}
{'Name': 'TransactionDate', 'Value': 20190223144807}
{'Name': 'PhoneNumber', 'Value': 254725696042}
```

One possibility is

```
>>> [x['Value'] for x in data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'] if x['Name'] == 'MpesaReceiptNumber'][0]
'NBN52K8A1J'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the library json. Then you can print its inner elements

import json

```
json_data = '{"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"22531-976234-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852","ResultCode":0,"ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.","CallbackMetadata":{"Item":[{"Name":"Amount","Value":1.00},{"Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber","Value":"NBN52K8A1J"},{"Name":"Balance"},{"Name":"TransactionDate","Value":20190223144807},{"Name":"PhoneNumber","Value":254725696042}]}}}}'
a = json.loads(json_data)
print(a["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][1]["Value"])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the json you will notice that the path to the data is not simply ['Body']['MpesaReceiptNumber']. In fact you have a list of dicts inside ['Item'] that needs to be searched.

[Parsed data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjsN0.png)

One suggestion is to run the following code to find the data you are looking for:

```py
import json
json_data = '{"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"22531-976234-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852","ResultCode":0,"ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.","CallbackMetadata":{"Item":[{"Name":"Amount","Value":1.00},{"Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber","Value":"NBN52K8A1J"},{"Name":"Balance"},{"Name":"TransactionDate","Value":20190223144807},{"Name":"PhoneNumber","Value":254725696042}]}}}}'
data = (json.loads(json_data))

list_data = data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item']

# Returns:
# [{'Name': 'Amount', 'Value': 1.0}, {'Name': 'MpesaReceiptNumber', 'Value':'NBN52K8A1J'}, {'Name': 'Balance'}, {'Name': 'TransactionDate', 'Value': 20190223144807}, {'Name': 'PhoneNumber', 'Value': 254725696042}]

# Now find Name: 'MpesaReceiptNumber' inside the dict list
find_it = next(item for item in list_data if item["Name"] == "MpesaReceiptNumber")
find_it = find_it['Value']

print (find_it)
```

Result

```
NBN52K8A1J
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there just have to get the the key value pair itself from the dicts and check if it is the name you wanted:

```
data = json.loads(json_data)
list_data = data['Body']["stkCallback"]['CallbackMetadata']['Item']
var: str

for x in list_data:
    if x['Name'] == 'MpesaReceiptNumber':
       var = x['Value']
       break

print(var)
```

You can use this in the future easily by replacing the if check with the name of something else so you can grab the value depending on a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I find using pprint to get the shape of the data structure is helpful when you're learning how to navigate it all out.

```
import json
import pprint

json_data = '{"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"22531-976234-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852","ResultCode":0,"ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.","CallbackMetadata":{"Item":[{"Name":"Amount","Value":1.00},{"Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber","Value":"NBN52K8A1J"},{"Name":"Balance"},{"Name":"TransactionDate","Value":20190223144807},{"Name":"PhoneNumber","Value":254725696042}]}}}}'
data = json.loads(json_data)

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Results in:

```
{'Body': {'stkCallback': {'CallbackMetadata': {'Item': [{'Name': 'Amount', 'Value': 1.0},
                                                        {'Name': 'MpesaReceiptNumber', 'Value': 'NBN52K8A1J'},
                                                        {'Name': 'Balance'},
                                                        {'Name': 'TransactionDate', 'Value': 20190223144807},
                                                        {'Name': 'PhoneNumber', 'Value': 254725696042}]},
                          'CheckoutRequestID': 'ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852',
                          'MerchantRequestID': '22531-976234-1',
                          'ResultCode': 0,
                          'ResultDesc': 'The service request is processed successfully.'}}}
```

So you should be able to see that `data["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"]` gets to to the depth you need for your data.

```
 >>> pprint.pprint(data["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"])

 [{'Name': 'Amount', 'Value': 1.0},
 {'Name': 'MpesaReceiptNumber', 'Value': 'NBN52K8A1J'},
 {'Name': 'Balance'},
 {'Name': 'TransactionDate', 'Value': 20190223144807},
 {'Name': 'PhoneNumber', 'Value': 254725696042}]
```

So next you need to iterate through that list and find a match (if one exists) for the `MpesaReceiptNumber` key.

```
receipt_no = None
for item in data["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"]:
    if item.get('Name') == 'MpesaReceiptNumber':
        receipt_no = item.get('Value')

print(f"The receipt # is: {receipt_no}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq`.

First off, it can "pretty print" any JSON data.

Put the value of `json_data` into a file `test.json`, and then show the formatted output of the JSON data with:

```
$ jq <test.json
{
  "Body": {
    "stkCallback": {
      "MerchantRequestID": "22531-976234-1",
      "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852",
      "ResultCode": 0,
      "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
      "CallbackMetadata": {
        "Item": [
          {
            "Name": "Amount",
            "Value": 1
          },
          {
            "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
            "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Balance"
          },
          {
            "Name": "TransactionDate",
            "Value": 20190223144807
          },
          {
            "Name": "PhoneNumber",
            "Value": 254725696042
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next, to extract values, a selector path needs to be given on the `jq` command line:

```
jq '.Body.stkCallback.CallbackMetadata.Item|.[]|select(.Name == "MpesaReceiptNumber")|.Value' test.json
"NBN52K8A1J"
```

Now to make this sequence easier to understand, let's break it down component by component.

To extract and return only the `.Body`:

```
$ jq '.Body' <test.json
{
  "stkCallback": {
    "MerchantRequestID": "22531-976234-1",
    "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852",
    "ResultCode": 0,
    "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
    "CallbackMetadata": {
      "Item": [
        {
          "Name": "Amount",
          "Value": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
          "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Balance"
        },
        {
          "Name": "TransactionDate",
          "Value": 20190223144807
        },
        {
          "Name": "PhoneNumber",
          "Value": 254725696042
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now let's fetch the `stkCallback` component:

```
$ jq '.Body.stkCallback' <test.json
{
  "MerchantRequestID": "22531-976234-1",
  "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_DMZ_250600506_23022019144745852",
  "ResultCode": 0,
  "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
  "CallbackMetadata": {
    "Item": [
      {
        "Name": "Amount",
        "Value": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
        "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Balance"
      },
      {
        "Name": "TransactionDate",
        "Value": 20190223144807
      },
      {
        "Name": "PhoneNumber",
        "Value": 254725696042
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ok, now the `callbackMetadata`:

```
$ jq '.Body.stkCallback.CallbackMetadata' <test.json
{
  "Item": [
    {
      "Name": "Amount",
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
      "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Balance"
    },
    {
      "Name": "TransactionDate",
      "Value": 20190223144807
    },
    {
      "Name": "PhoneNumber",
      "Value": 254725696042
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, the `Item` part:

```
$ jq '.Body.stkCallback.CallbackMetadata.Item' <test.json
[
  {
    "Name": "Amount",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
    "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Balance"
  },
  {
    "Name": "TransactionDate",
    "Value": 20190223144807
  },
  {
    "Name": "PhoneNumber",
    "Value": 254725696042
  }
]
```

Notice that the result is an *array* of list items?  Let's filter the data *out* of the array:

```
$ jq '.Body.stkCallback.CallbackMetadata.Item|.[]' <test.json
{
  "Name": "Amount",
  "Value": 1
}
{
  "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
  "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
}
{
  "Name": "Balance"
}
{
  "Name": "TransactionDate",
  "Value": 20190223144807
}
{
  "Name": "PhoneNumber",
  "Value": 254725696042
}
```

Now the result is just the list of tuples, each with a "Name" and "Value".  So, let's select just the one we (you) wanted:

```
$ jq '.Body.stkCallback.CallbackMetadata.Item|.[]|select(.Name == "MpesaReceiptNumber")' <test.json
{
  "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
  "Value": "NBN52K8A1J"
}
```

Cool.  We've got the tuple we wanted.  Let's extract just the value now:

```
$ jq '.Body.stkCallback.CallbackMetadata.Item|.[]|select(.Name == "MpesaReceiptNumber")|.Value' <test.json
"NBN52K8A1J"
```

And, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get the value associated with a specific `CallbackMetadata` item name:

```
json_string = '''
    {
        "Body": {
            "stkCallback": {
               ...
    }
'''

json_data = json.loads(json_string)

for item in json_data["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"]:
    if item["Name"] == "MpesaReceiptNumber":
        print(item["Value"])  # -> NBN52K8A1J
```